# LINQ to SQL - Best way for reading data from one to many mapped tables

Tags: c#, linq

Which of the following is the best way to read properties from a related table using LINQ to SQL?

```
var users = (from user in db.users.Where(u => u.Id > 10)
    select new User
    {
        UserName = u.UserName
        UserId = u.Id,
        Address1 = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).Address1,
        Address2 = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).Address2,
        Address3 = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).Address3,
        City = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).City,
        State = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).State,
        Zip = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress).Zip
    }).ToList();
```

OR

```
var users = (from user in db.users.Where(u => u.Id > 10)
    select new
    {
        UserName = u.UserName
        UserId = u.Id,
        Address = u.UserAddress.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsHomeAddress)
    }).ToList();

users.ForEach(u => {
    u.Address1 = u.Address.Address1,
    u.Address2 = u.Address.Address2,
    u.Address3 = u.Address.Address3,
    u.City = u.Address.City,
    u.State = u.Address.State,
    u.Zip = u.Address.Zip
});
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Well - in the first example, you will only get the first address for a given user. If you want all addresses for a given user, the first way won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using let, i.e.:

```
var users = (
    from user in db.users
    where user.Id > 10
    let homeAddress = user.UserAddress.First(a => a.IsHomeAddress)
    select new User
    {
        UserName = user.UserName
        UserId = user.Id,
        Address1 = homeAddress.Address1,
        Address2 = homeAddress.Address2,
        Address3 = homeAddress.Address3,
        City = homeAddress.City,
        State = homeAddress.State,
        Zip = homeAddress.Zip
    }).ToList();
```